# c# read data from specific table and multiple columns in word document

Tags: c#

I need to read data from a word document that has 3 tables with 
multiple columns.

I managed to read data for all my table and show them in datagridView 
but it only shows data from column1 and i dont know how to distinguish between 
the different tables in the document.

I am using the assembly 
`using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;`

my code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create an instance of the Open File Dialog Box
        var openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        // Set filter options and filter index
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Word Documents (.docx)|*.docx|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
        openFileDialog1.Multiselect = false;

        // Call the ShowDialog method to show the dialog box.
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;

        var word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        object path = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        object readOnly = true;
        var docs = word.Documents.Open(ref path, ref miss, ref readOnly,
                                       ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss,
                                       ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss,
                                       ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss,
                                       ref miss);

        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("explaineText", "col1");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("CustomerText", "col2");


        foreach (Table tb in docs.Tables)
        //Is it possible to add a condition statement here like 
        //if(tb{number} = 1){ do something } 
        {
            for (int row = 1; row <= tb.Rows.Count; row++)
            {
                var cell = tb.Cell(row, 1);
                var text = cell.Range.Text;
                //here i try to assing col to column 2 

                var col = tb.Cell(row, 2);
                var custtext = cell.Range.Text;
                //here i try to add the text from column2 in dataGridView 
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(text, custtext);
            }
            // text now contains the content of the cell.
        }

        foreach (Table tb in docs.Tables)
        {
            // insert code here to get text from cells in first column
            // and insert into datatable.
        }

        ((_Document)docs).Close();
        ((_Application)word).Quit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using these loops inside your Tables loop:

```
foreach(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Row row in tb.Rows) 
{
    foreach(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Cell cell in row.Cells) 
    {
        //do something with all the cells
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, for some reason i get this error when adding this loop 
Error CS1061 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Cells' 
the row does not have a Cells member

Comment: Good that you got it to work. Perhaps you have to declare the row and cell variables as Row and Cell, for it to recognize the actual types

Comment: Also, in my experience, if you are not actually opening a word document and showing it to the user (in word), i would suggest using the open xml sdk for reading and manipulating word documents: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk